# add div to page from the code behind Asp.net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, code-behind

Hello I have a item list that shows on my asp.net page like this:

```
    <div class="search-result-item">

            <div class="image">
                <img src="images/1.png"/>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png"/>
            </div>
            <div class="header">
                Title
            </div>
            <div class="message">
                Message
            </div>
            <div class="keywords">
                key1 | key2 | key3
            </div>

            <div class="links">
                <a href="link.html">Go to</a>
            </div>

        </div>
```

This shows a predefined layout for an item on the page.

Items are generated in the code behind.

I want for each item to create a div like the one above on the page.
How can I do that using the code behind?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create a Control and add it to your page.

There are a large range of controls, but if you want that exact markup, and don't need any server-side processing, the [LiteralControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx) control is probably the most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [repeater control](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp) You create a control that basically connects to datasource and then repeats info based on the data. Very crude description sorry. Look at it on Google.